# AngularJS - watching the scope of directive's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive, watch

I've built a plunker to test things out, but I must not be understanding some angular fundamentals.

Why is the directive's link function not able to watch a property (scope.featureAttributes) on the directive's controller's scope.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rWG5NEp6TRYfP7l1HHDw

thanks for your help

Comment: Your directive is creating an isolate scope with 'scope: {}'.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm not looking to inherit the scope from a parent controller.

Comment: You're right, I do need the parent's scope to access the increment method... but removing the isolate scope still doesn't trigger an update on the property I'm watching

Comment: Yeah, heres a fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/b2VbKtPSBqGgcd0dVEmj?p=preview. zeroflag is right, watchCollection was not in 1.0.8.

Comment: thanks aet... I did actually have my code working in the same manner as your plunker, but I had wanted to remove the injection of the service from my directive (generally not best practice?), and instead use a service-injected-controller in the directive.  Am I right in saying that directives can't watch for changes on the scope of their controller, if that scope is updated via a service/factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `$watchCollection`. The plnkr includes Angular 1.0.8. `$watchCollection` was introduced in a later version.